# Importing bootstrap into nextjs - document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am trying to import bootstrap 5.3.2 (not react-bootstrap) into a NextJS 14.1.0 project that uses new the new App Router. I would like to use individual BS components *programmatically*  (not via data-attrs).

I got it to work but (I do get the tooltips) but I cannot get rid of this error 500 with each hard refresh. The console shows this exact message:

```
 ⨯ node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js (803:18) @ document
 ⨯ ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/rsilva/Desktop/bs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./app/TooltipComponent.js:9:67)
    at (ssr)/./app/TooltipComponent.js (/Users/rsilva/Desktop/bs/.next/server/app/page.js:162:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/rsilva/Desktop/bs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
```

Here's my relevant code:

layout.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import BootstrapProvider from "./providers/bootstrap";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="container my-5">
        <BootstrapProvider/>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

my BS provider (bootstrap.js):

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from 'react';

function BootstrapProvider() {
  useEffect(() => {

    async function loadBootstrap() {
      const bootstrap = await import('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
      window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
    }

    loadBootstrap();
    
  }, []);

  return null;
}

export default BootstrapProvider;
```

page.js

```
import { TooltipComponent } from "./TooltipComponent";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      
     <TooltipComponent title="Test">
        test tooltip
      </TooltipComponent>
      
    </main>
  );
}
```

and finally the actual component that uses Tooltip programatically:

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";

export function TooltipComponent({
  children,
  title = "Missing tooltip 'title' property",
  placement = "top",
  trigger = "hover",
}) {
  const tooltipRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (title) {
      const tooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipRef.current, {
        title: title,
        placement: placement,
        trigger: trigger,
        container: "body",
      });
      return () => {
        tooltip.dispose();
      };
    }
  }, [title]);

  return <span ref={tooltipRef}>{children}</span>;
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Script" component to include "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" js file in layout.js
Not needed Additional component.
Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is definitely cleaner IMO but it still returns the error. One thing to note is that the error happens when i import the individual modules, e.g:
```
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";
```
here's the updated layout:
```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Script from "next/script";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="container my-5">
        {children}
        <Script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: New finding: It appears that one doesn't even need the bootstrap <Script/> import tag. However, the instant you try to import Tooltip, Popover, Offcanvas, Modal etc from bootstrap, the error 500 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/).

It provides bootstrap for react. You don't have to create Boostrap Provider or  link vanilla boostrap to window.

[Example Tooltip](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/overlays/#examples)

**EDIT**

Why don't you add bootstrap js in the script tag and instead of trying to import Tooltip, use it like the way you use in vanilla js or jquery.

```
import Script from 'next/script'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" strategy="afterInteractive" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Use tooltip in component

```
"use client";

export function TooltipComponent({
  children,
  title = "Missing tooltip 'title' property",
  placement = "top",
  trigger = "hover",
}) {
  return <span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement={placement} title={title}>{children}</span>;
}
```

Comment: Than you for your suggestion. I did consider it but react-bootstrap's components are too rigid for the UI's I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

import the minified Bootstrap CSS file into the Next.js entry pages/_app.js file

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; 
import bootstrap CSS import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {   return <Component {...pageProps} />; }

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't an issue importing the CSS. It happens when I try to import individual JS modules from bootstrap.min.js. Also this is the new version of Next that uses layout.js instead of _app.sj

Answer (score 0):

The `ReferenceError: document is not defined` occurs because Bootstrap JavaScript code is executed in SSR (i.e., server-side rendering), where there is no DOM. **But Bootstrap's JavaScript relies on the DOM.** Consequently, Bootstrap's JavaScript is trying to access the document object during SSR, but it cannot find it because there is no DOM. That's why you're getting this error.

To solve this error, you need to load the Bootstrap JavaScript only on the client side, where the DOM is available. You need to adapt the `TooltipComponent.tsx` file. See the comments below.

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
// Remove this
// import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";

export function TooltipComponent({
  children,
  title = "Missing tooltip 'title' property",
  placement = "top",
  trigger = "hover",
}) {
  const tooltipRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add this
    const { Tooltip } = require("bootstrap");

    if (title) {
      const tooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipRef.current, {
        title: title,
        placement: placement,
        trigger: trigger,
        container: "body",
      });
      return () => {
        tooltip.dispose();
      };
    }
  }, [title]);

  return <span ref={tooltipRef}>{children}</span>;
}
```

Doing this, I managed to solve the error, as seen in the screenshot below (the screenshot was taken after the page refresh).

[image: Screenshot]

If you still have problems, let me know because I started the Next.js app from scratch, so my code might be slightly different. In this case, I will edit my answer and add full code for all files (`layout.tsx`, `page.tsx`, `tooltip.tsx`, `bootstrap.js`, etc.).

Comment: You are a rockstar, sir. This solved the issue. I understood the underlying issue but not how or why the boostrap code was running on the server if I had "use client" in the top of bootstrap.js provider?? Is the purpose of that line to force the code to run on the clientside only?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the `"use client"` indicates that the code following should be included in the client-side bundle and should not be executed during server-side rendering (SSR). To be honest, I don't know why `"use client"` wasn't enough in your case. It also puzzles me. I just figured out that this solution works.